# Как перевести человеку деньги на карту с любого счета с помощью python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Мне нужно чтобы чат-бот в телеграмме умел переводить деньги человеку за выполнение задания, безопасность не особо важна, бот будет использоваться для личных целей. Есть ли какие-то API, чтобы это реализовать? Буду очень благодарен за пример. Очень прошу не отправлять меня читать документации, а ответить что подойдет под мою задачу. Видел вариант с Qiwi API, они больше не выдают токены для ботов.